# MySQL Syntax Error for a complex query

Tags: mysql

Here is the complex query that I wrote but can't figure out what's the problem:

```
SELECT student.progid,
   student.batch
FROM   (student
    JOIN registers
      ON student.studentid = registers.studentid)
   JOIN (SELECT offers.courseno
         FROM   (offers
                JOIN instructor
                  ON offers.instructorid = instructor.instructorid))
     ON offers.courseno = registers.courseno
WHERE  instructor.instructorname = 'P M Jaat'
   AND ( offers.acadyear LIKE '2007%'
          OR offers.acadyear LIKE '2008%'
          OR offers.acadyear LIKE '2009%'
          OR offers.acadyear LIKE '2010%'
          OR offers.acadyear LIKE '2011%' );
```

This results in an error, but I'm going to leave it to others to tell you what that is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'R1
    JOIN (SELECT
```

Comment: Can you show us the syntax error you are seeing?

Comment: `FROM (student...` is that correct?

Comment: student is the table name. It's correct.

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to the positioning of your `(` and the closing `)`

Comment: @Kisaragi aah, I got an exact answer for what you wanted to say :)

Answer (score 3):

Double check your parenthesis.  Your `FROM` clause is

```
(student JOIN registers ON student.StudentID=registers.StudentID)
```

Which doesn't make sense.

What you want is:

```
FROM (student)
JOIN registers AS r1
    ON (student.StudentID=registers.StudentID)
```

Or you can just lose the extra parenthesis:

```
FROM student
JOIN registers AS r1
    ON student.StudentID=registers.StudentID
```

P.S. You also had your `AS r1` in the wrong spot.

UPDATE: You need parenthesis when you are using *subqueries*.

```
FROM student
JOIN registers
    ON student.studentid = registers.studentid
JOIN(
    SELECT courseno
    FROM offers
    JOIN instructor
    ON offers.instructorid = instructor.instructorid
) AS r2 ON offers.courseno = registers.courseno
```

Comment: aaaah, why isn't MySQL syntax much simpler like C or Java!

Comment: I do not want registers as r1 though. It's showing derived table must have it's own alias error without it.

Comment: What do you want `r1` to be then?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're after something like this...

```
    SELECT r.progid
         , r.batch
      FROM student s
      JOIN registers r
        ON r.studentid = s.studentid 
      JOIN offers o
        ON o.courseno = r.courseno
      JOIN instructor i
        ON i.instructorid = o.instructorid  
     WHERE i.instructorname = 'P M Jaat' 
       AND o.acadyear BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2011-12-31';
```

Comment: This seems much better than my answer.  No reason to use subqueries here, just JOIN everything you need.

Comment: It worked! Just so you know, it didn't worked cause my acad year is not in your format. I edited into my format. This one is so simple. It makes me wonder why I think so much complex.

Comment: @Mr.Robot A better idea might be to adjust your acad year to *my* format!! It will be faster (although your data set is probably quite small)